# Generate random points in a Voronoi region, and creating Voronoi regions with high dimensional data

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, octave, voronoi

I am using the k-means clustering algorithm, and for each cluster centroid, I am trying to generate the n-dimensional Voronoi region for the centroid. After which I need to generate random points from the Voronoi region.

I have tried using Matlab/Octave and scipy to get the n-dimensional Voronoi regions. But I have two questions.

- Once I have the generated the vertices and regions, how can I generate random data from a region
- Is it possible to construct Voronoi regions if the number of cluster centroids is less than n, the number of dimensions

Edit -

My primary objective is to generate a codebook. I have 60k n-dimensional data points, and I want to create a codebook of say, 512 codewords, where each codeword is n-dimensional. The codebook is, an approximation of the original data. Clustering would be one way of doing that. Since k-means will take a long time, I wanted to use the Adaptive Iterative LBG (by Shen Furao and Osamu Hasegawa) where the process is -

- Find the cluster centroid with largest error - lets call it C_large
- Generate a random point in the Voronoi region of C_large, lets call it C_new
- Run k-means with the data points in the voronoi region , with only two centroids, C_large and C_new

This will run much faster than k-means, since each time k-means is run with  a subset of the total data points and only two centroids.

However, the algorithm begins with k=1. But until k>n (where the data is n-dimensional) I cant find the Voronoi regions using scipy or Octave.

So if I have a single centroid, as C, Running voronoin(C) in Octave gives me

```
error: voronoin: number of points must be greater than their dimension
```

So is there a way to generate Voronoi regions in such situations.

For the second quesion I had, a good answer has been given.

I would like to ask to ask another related question though. Since voronoin(C) in Octave wont work for when number of points in C is less than n (# of dimensions), I tried running simple k-means 50 times, to get 50 cluster centroids. Then when I try to run voronoin(C), where C is a matrix of size 50X36, so there are 50 cluster centroids, each is a 36 dimensional point, I get the following error -

```
qhull error (qh_memalloc): insufficient memory

While executing:  | qhull v Qbb Qx
Options selected for Qhull 2009.1 2009/06/14:
  voronoi  Qbbound-last  Qxact-merge  _zero-centrum  Pgood
  Q3-no-merge-vertices-dim-high  _max-width 1.6  Error-roundoff 9.4e-14
  _one-merge 7.6e-12  _near-inside 3.8e-11  Visible-distance 5.6e-13
  U-coplanar-distance 5.6e-13  Width-outside 1.1e-12  _wide-facet 3.4e-12
Last point added to hull was p23.

At error exit:

Voronoi diagram by the convex hull of 50 points in 40-d:

  Number of Voronoi regions: 48
  Total number of nearly incident points: 2
  Number of Voronoi vertices: 0

Statistics for:  | qhull v Qbb Qx

  Number of points processed: 48
  Number of hyperplanes created: 5070358
  Number of facets in hull: 4320576
  Number of distance tests for qhull: 1525377

error: voronoin: qhull failed
warning: voronoin: qhull did not free -2099969864 bytes of long memory (1 pieces)
```

I think I'm doing something wrong, I cant figure out what though. I also check out the options that I can provide along with voronoin() present here

http://www.qhull.org/html/qh-quick.htm#options

But I cant seem to figure out if any of them will help me here

Here is a link to the 50 cluster centroids

https://www.mediafire.com/?7flqqx66mmc4258

And this is the code I am running

```
C = dlmread('clust_centroids');
[Vc,Vf] = voronoin(C);
```

This gives me the error I've given above.

Comment: You're a bit broad in your question, please stick to either python, matlab, or octave and post your attempts here. Best if you supply your code with a sample data, and explanation of where and how you're stuck.

Comment: Oh, sure sure, Ive added more details, along with the sample data. If I missed anything, let me know, I'll add it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you are going to do this for the k-means clustering algorithm. Are you going to generate some samples for testing? If so, just generate some random points within the entire space, and label them after then.

If you insist to generate a point within a specific region for some purpose, it would be very hard no matter you represent the Voronoi as a bitmap or vectors. I think a random algorithm would be of help:

```
Generate a random point p within the Voronoi region of centroid t
1. generate a random point p within the entre space;
2. compute the distance between p and each centroid;
3. if the distance of p and t is the minimal distance, output p;
   else go to step 1.
```

The expected time complexity of this algorithm is `O(n^2)` on average, and it's easy to implement. Though its time cost is not stable.

For your second question, yes, it's possible. Consider if you have 2 points in a 3 dimension space, they could be carved into 2 Voronoi regions by a plane.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate random points in a certain volume, just pick a cartesian aligned box enclosing that volume and create points in the box at random. Check if they are in the volume, keep them if so else discard them.

Regarding your second question, I must ask are you not re-inventing a support vector machine here?